# What does img[@rel= mean in this jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, selector

```
var _thumb = $('.galleria img[@rel="'+_src+'"]');
```

Full source [here](http://files.cnblogs.com/opper/galleria.js)

Is it a deprecated selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [attribute selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeHas#attribute) that will find all `<img>` elements with a `rel` attribute equal to the value to the right of the `=` sign.

And yes, the `@` portion was deprecated as of jQuery 1.2 and removed completely in 1.3. Now you'd just use `"img[rel=...]"`.

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

> **Note:** In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style
>   selectors were removed (they were
>   previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2).
>   Simply remove the '@' symbol from your
>   selectors in order to make them work
>   again.

Answer (score 0):

`@` used to be required in [attribute selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors), but no longer in jQuery 1.2 + and removed in jQuery 1.3

Answer (score 0):

It was deprecated in version 1.2 and removed in version 1.3.

From the [jQuery selector documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

> Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style
>   selectors were removed (they were
>   previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2).
>   Simply remove the '@' symbol from your
>   selectors in order to make them work
>   again.